# Input missing values in categorical time series

Tags: categorical-data, random-forest, missing-data

I have a dataset similar to

```
id    value   month
1     A        02
1     A        03
1     B        04
2     NA       02
2     NA       03
2     A        04
3     C        02
3     NA       03
3     C        04
```

Then I pivot to month_col:

```
id    value_02    value_03    value_04
1     A           A           B
2     NA          NA          A
3     C           NA          C
```

I have two kinds of missing values here: the first one, of the id 2, means that this id was not present on the database on the months 02 and 03 and entered the database on month 04. The other kind is the id 3, that on the month 03 had an error in the process.

I want to use these variables on a random forest classifier (I have a target column, now shown here.) So far I tried to

- most frequent item: this can keep the NA value if this is the most frequent one
- most frequent valid item: it seems to be the best scenario, but can introduce bias
- drop line: my dataset is rather limited so drop values would not be desired

What is the best approach to fill these missing values without introducing bias?